# vectorization in xts is there a simple solution

Tags: r, xts

```
set.seed(2)
library(xts)

x <- sample(1:5,10,replace = T)
x.xts <- xts(x, order.by = seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), length = 10, by = "min"))
```

I have xts object `x.xts` and i want apply to him vectorized operation something like this

```
x[1] > x

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

but when i do this i get not what i expect

```
x.xts[1] > x.xts

                       e1
2023-12-06 10:13:16 FALSE
```

I can get what i want if i convert `x.xts[1]` to vector

```
as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts[1])) > x.xts

                     [,1]
2023-12-06 10:13:16 FALSE
2023-12-06 10:14:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:15:16 FALSE
2023-12-06 10:16:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:17:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:18:16 FALSE
2023-12-06 10:19:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:20:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:21:16  TRUE
2023-12-06 10:22:16  TRUE
```

but this `as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts[1]))` looks bulky and there are a lot of conversions in it, I would like to reduce this if possible because I will be running the code many times.

is there a way to make the expression `as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts[1])) > x.xts` closer to `x.xts[1] > x.xts`

---

And the performance looks terrible

```
 f <- function(x.xts) { xx = as.vector(coredata(x.xts)); xx < xx[1L] }

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   x[1] > x , 
+   as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts[1])) > x.xts,
+   f(x.xts))
Unit: nanoseconds
                                       expr    min       lq     mean   median     uq     max neval
                                   x[1] > x    570   1141.0   2229.6   2281.0   2851    5702   100
 as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts[1])) > x.xts 526830 535382.5 565658.3 545075.5 562180  872919   100
                                   f(x.xts)  29078  30789.0 116358.9  34495.0  37916 8096878   100
>
```

Comment: Your option does not eliminate the unnecessary transformations that you have at the beginning

Comment: Well, my comment `xx = as.vector(coredata(x.xts)); xx < xx[1L]` (direction of comparison corrected now) should be understood w.r.t. performance in terms of run time. On my machine it is more than two times faster than the demonstrated solution, for `1e6`.

Comment: Yes, your version looks much better

Comment: But the question was whether it was possible to get rid of unnecessary transformations altogether

Comment: Indeed, there are two parts: elegant code & performance w.r.t. run time. I address the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get an xts object back then:

```
x.xts[[1L]] > x.xts
##                      [,1]
## 2023-12-06 08:24:29 FALSE
## 2023-12-06 08:25:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:26:29 FALSE
## 2023-12-06 08:27:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:28:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:29:29 FALSE
## 2023-12-06 08:30:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:31:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:32:29  TRUE
## 2023-12-06 08:33:29  TRUE
```

If you want to get a plain vector back and speed matters then this is slightly faster than `f` in the question:

```
x.xts[[1L]] > structure(x.xts, class = NULL)[, 1L]
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

### Update

Fixed some copy and paste errors.

Comment: Excellent!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> And the performance looks terrible

Addressing speed improvement, basic "pre-conversion" might help:

```
xx = as.vector(coredata(x.xts)); xx < xx[1L]
```

Obviously, this does not make the code shorter.

---

```r
f = \(x.xts) { as.vector(zoo::coredata(x.xts)); xx < xx[1L] }
```